Is the ordered pair definition $(,):=\{,\{,\}\}$ a good definition?
In answer to this post

There is no one fixed way to define an ordered pair in terms of sets. It is also common to define an ordered pair as $(,):=\{,\{,\}\}$. One can prove that $\{x_1, \{x_1,y_1\}\} = \{x_2, \{x_2,y_2\}\} \iff x_1 = x_2 \text{ and }y_1=y_2 \label{1}\tag{$*$}.$

I've tried the proof, and the process is questionable:
take simplest case when
$$
x=y,\, u=v,\, \langle x,y\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle \iff \{,\{\}\}=\{u,\{u\}\},$$
to which $x=u,\{\}=\{u\}$ is a solution. As we can immediately see,  also $x=\{u\},u=\{\}$ can be a solution as long as there exist a set such that $x=\{\{x\}\}$, i.e. if $x$ is a set containing a set containing itself. Now searching the internet for an example of a set containing itself, I've found this Quora Q&A, where it states that in ZFC set theory there isn't a set containing itself (so I think it also means a set containing a set containing itself wouldn't exist). On the other hand,
other non-ZFC set theories allows a set containing itself to exist (so I assume a set containing a set containing itself would also exist under such theory), so under this theory
we cannot prove \eqref{1}.
On the contrary to Kuratowski's definition $\langle x,y\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, Wiener's definition
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\{\{\{x\},\emptyset\},\{\{y\}\}
$$ is a good one because it don't rely on such a particular axiom of set theory. It works in set theories other than ZFC, even works in naive set theory.

It wouldn't appear in books if it weren't a perfectly acceptable definition.  And you can't really say that something will work in any version of set theory regardless of axioms without implicitly imagining your set theory to have certain properties which can be taken to be axioms.  I would also say that the whole point of phrasing concepts in terms of set theory is to show that we can model it there, but once we have, the particulars of the model become entirely unimportant, and it is better to think of the properties you want objects to have, not specific models or constructions.

"Kuratowski definition ...  is good definition because [it doesn't] rely on set theory axiom" It is not true: we need axiom to assert that ${ x }$ and ${ x,y }$ exist.

$x \neq {x}$ so $x={{x}}$ does not contain itself. You only have to be concerned if $x={x}$

@Aaron could you point out a book that uses this definition, so I can see the proof? I suspect the proof would uses zfc such that x={{x}} can't exist. (What I learn is Kuratowski definition)

@CyclotomicField what do you mean? $x \neq {x}$, but $x$ can still equal to ${{x}}$. Yes, ${{x}}$ contains ${x}$ not $x$, but we only need $x={{x}}$

$x$ can be arbitrary but ${x}$ is always a set. Singletons are not the element they contain.

we only need $x={{x}}$ for this post's definition, $<x,x>=<u,u>$, if $x={{x}}$, we let $u={x}$ and still satisfy the equation, which is a bad because our want $<x,x>=<u,u> \iff x=u $

As other commenters have pointed out, there are multiple possible viable set-theoretic representations of ordered pairs. But it seems like the OP's specific difficulty is in understanding why the convention of $\{x, \{x, y\}\}$ actually "works", so to speak.
I'd argue it as follows (I’m assuming a “pure” set theory, without “urelements”): The key is whether, for any instance of $\{x, \{x, y\}\}$, one can unambiguously tell which element is intended as the "first" and which element is the "second". This is indeed possible, because necessarily $x \in \{x, y\}$ but it cannot be true that $\{x, y\} \in x$ (that would violate the Axiom of Foundation). So we can tell which element is the "first", and then trivially we know which is "second" (I've assumed $x$ and $y$ are distinct -- a nearly identical argument pertains if $x = y$)
So $\{x, \{x, y\}\}$ seems like a viable convention for representing ordered pairs, but I think the Kuratowski convention is preferrable in that it's just clearer how it works (as evidenced by OP's perplexity). Also it's not totally obvious to me that $\{x, \{x, y\}\}$ would work for every case in non-well-founded set theories (lacking an Axiom of Foundation)

It can definitely be valuable to know multiple implementations of the same concept, and to keep track of what axioms are required for a given implementation. (For a particularly subtle example of this, see the notion of "flat pairing function" in the context of $\mathsf{NF}$.) However, your title and some of the body of the question (" the process is questionable") overstates the case; there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a definition which is successful in the context within which you are working.
So there's nothing mathematically wrong with what you've written above - the ordered pair $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ is less "axiomatically flexible" than certain other implementations - but that doesn't mean that that notion is bad in any way.
